# Programmatically Call All Functions In Object? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

As the title states, is there a way to programmatically call all the functions in an object? They don't have to be called in a certain order and none of them depend on each other for any state etc. What I had originally tried which seemed the most logical (at least to me) was

```
var object = {
    eventOne(){
        console.log("eventOne")
    },
    eventTwo(){
      console.log("eventTwo")
    },
    .......more events
}
//and then this for calling them
for(event in object){
  event();
}
```

but that just ends up in a event() is not a function error. As of now there aren't enough events in the object for me to be too bothered and not just call them manually but there will soon be about 20 or so and they need to be registered in multiple locations, and I'm also curious to know if it's even possible :)

Comment: Iterate and call the values not keys. Check if the type is a function.

Answer (score 2):

`for..in` loops iterate over the *property names*, not the values. If some of an object's values are functions, and you want to call those functions, then iterate over the *values* instead, and make sure to do a `typeof` check first to ensure you don't call non-functions:

```js
var object = {
    eventOne(){
        console.log("eventOne")
    },
    eventTwo(){
      console.log("eventTwo")
    },
};
Object.values(object).forEach((val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'function') val();
});
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before as this is the same way it works in Python. Appreciate it!

Comment: @DannyCanter Note that there will be a difference when using `Object.values` vs. `Object.keys` (with something like `object[key]()`) and when the methods use `this`, since when just using `val()` the `object` context is lost, which doesn’t happen for `object[key]()` or, alternatively, `val.call(object)`.

Comment: @Xufox I'm aware of that and luckily none of the events use `this` so it's not an issue. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

`event` is the property name. Use `object[propertyName]()`

```js
var object = {
    eventOne(){
        console.log("eventOne")
    },
    eventTwo(){
      console.log("eventTwo")
    }
}
//and then this for calling them
for(event in object){
 object[ event]();
}
```